# React child component not rendering props from parent value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I have a simple app that makes a call to a weather API and displays it in a child component.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Forecast } from './forecast'
import Card from './components/Card'

function App() {
  const apiURL = "https://weather.cc.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?apiKey=XXXXX&product=forecast_7days&name=Berlin"
  const [weatherCards, setCards] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getWeather = async() => {
      var forecastList = []
      const res = await fetch(apiURL)
      const data = await res.json()
      const forecasts = data.forecasts.forecastLocation.forecast
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let iconLink = forecasts[i].iconLink
        let iconName = forecasts[i].iconName
        let utcTime = forecasts[i].utcTime
        let temperature = forecasts[i].temperature
        let forecast = new Forecast(iconLink, iconName, utcTime, temperature)
        forecastList.push(forecast)
        //console.log(forecastList)
      }
      setCards(forecastList)
    }
    getWeather()
  
  }, [])


  return (
    <div >
      <h1>My Weather dashboard</h1>
      <div className="container">
          <Card props={weatherCards[0]} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

**Card.js**

```
const Card = ( props ) => {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <img src={props.iconLink}/>
            <div className="caption">{props.iconName}</div>
            <h3>Day: {props.day}</h3>
            <h3>time: {props.time}</h3>
            <h3>temperature: {props.temperature}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Forecast.js**

```
export class Forecast {
    constructor(iconLink, iconName, utcTime, temperature) {
        this.iconLink = iconLink
        this.iconName = iconName
        this.utcTime = utcTime
        this.temperature =temperature
    }
}
```

However, my Card component does not render the Forecast object attributes. I am not sure what I am doing wrong? The code seems very straightforward.

Comment: Other than you will access X of undefined on the initial (*and any subsequent) renders until the `weatherCards` state is populated, what is the issue? Or is this just it?

Comment: Even though I am setting the card state in UseEffect, it is not updating the `weatherCards` variable no matter how long I wait. I want to be able to pass the props to the `Card` component when the data is ready.

Comment: What is `let forecast = new Forecast(iconLink, iconName, utcTime, temperature)` doing?

Comment: It creates a new `Forecast` class that I have defined. I have updated in the post

Comment: I think Viet has the answer below, but why not just `setCards(data.forecasts.forecastLocation.forecast.slice(0,5))` and call it a day there, the for-loop and `Forecast` class are extraneous and unnecessary.

Comment: I think you are right, that is much better. I think I created a forecast class because not all of the object attributes that is returned from the API will be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass props name `props` so you need to use `props.props.iconLink` in the `Card` component.

OR you can pass props like this:

```
<Card {...weatherCards[0]} />
```